# The process of calling python library function

Tags: python, bytecode

I'm trying to understand the process of calling python function, I created simple `.pyc` file that calls `os.listdir('.')`,
I saw that `os` and `listdir` are saved in the `co_names` table, When executing `CALL_FUNCTION` bytecode instruction, how `os` library is being identified? is it by its name using the `co_names` table? is python start searching for module named `os.pyc`? if so how python knows where is the offset of the bytecode of the function called in the `.pyc` module?

Thanks.

**dis module bytecode snippet**

```
  5          28 LOAD_NAME                0 (os)
             31 LOAD_ATTR                2 (listdir)
             34 LOAD_CONST               3 ('.')
             37 CALL_FUNCTION            1
```

Answer (score 5):

Python's virtual machine is stack-based. References to Python objects are pushed onto the stack, and an opcode pulls one or more of these off, does some operation, and usually pushes the result back on the stack for use by the next opcode.

As an aside, you might find disassembling a simple arithmetic calculation interesting (the operations must be completely reordered to work in this format). Or read up on FORTH; Python's VM is not dissimilar to FORTH's, but the actual FORTH *language* reflects its VM in a way that Python's does not. Anyway, on with the explanation...

The `LOAD_NAME` opcode gets a reference to the `os` object. (It happens to be a module, but it doesn't matter what kind of object it is, it works the same with all kinds of objects.) The reference is placed on top of the stack.

(This doesn't search for or load the module. Python has already imported a reference to `os` with a previous `import` statement, and is merely retrieving this reference from the global variables.)

The `LOAD_ATTR` opcode gets a reference to the `listdir` object of whatever object is referenced at the top of the stack. (Again, this reference is a function, but that doesn't matter.) The object reference at the top of the stack is popped off and the result of the `LOAD_ATTR` is pushed on.

The `LOAD_CONST` opcode gets a reference to the string `'.'` and pushes it on top of the stack.

Now the `CALL_FUNCTION` pops 1 reference off the stack. This is the reference to the string `'.'`, the argument to `os.listdir`. (It knows to pop 1 reference because the operand of `CALL_FUNCTION` is 1. If the function took more arguments, there would be more `LOAD` opcodes and the operand of the `CALL_FUNCTION` opcode would be higher.) It pops another reference off the stack, which is the reference to the `os.listdir` function. It then calls the function with the arguments. The return value of the function is then pushed on the stack, where it can be used by further opcodes.

As you have discovered, the names `os` and `listdir` are stored in a table, `co_names`. The operands to the `LOAD_NAME` and `LOAD_ATTR` opcodes are indices into this table. The `'.'` is handled similarly, except it's stored in the `co_consts` table.

Comment: so `IMPORT_NAME` instruction look for `os.pyc` file? the module is being identified by its name only? also how python know the position of `listdir` function bytecode within `os.pyc` file?

Comment: No, as I explained, `IMPORT_NAME` looks for `os` in the global variables. It is there because it was previously imported using the `import` statement. The way Python knows the location of the `listdir` function is that it's in the `os` module's namespace, i.e., that module's globals.

Comment: "is merely retrieving this reference from the global variables" - technically, it checks the scopes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules and this case it finds it in the global scope.